# Is there a way in CSS to use "last defined rule"?

Tags: css

I'm not sure how to explain this if not with examples.

Let's say I have this class

```
.padding1 {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

applied to this element

```
<div class="myDiv padding1"></div>
```

whith its own rules defined later that will override the `.padding1` rule. How to tell `.myDiv` to default to the last useful rule defined in .padding1?

```
.myDiv {
    padding-top: 0; 
}
.specialPage .myDiv {
   padding-top: /* ignore my override */
}
```

I know I could do it the opposite way but I was wondering if this can be done in this way instead which can be useful in some complex designs.

UPDATE: I was of course asking to see if there's a rule I'm missing. I don't want to declare it again, nor use initial or inherit.

Comment: I think you can do it by add **!important** to style like: ``` .padding1 {
    padding-top: 100px !important;
} ```

Comment: Here is the doc about overriding rules in CSS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

I just found out about this, there is a possible way to revert css styles using [`revert-layer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert-layer).

⚠ ***Warning*** ⚠ : As of 2022, this keyword is **experimental** and not widely compatible. Currently only for Firefox and Firefox Android v97.

> The revert-layer CSS keyword rolls back the value of a property in a cascade layer to the value of the property in a CSS rule matching the element in a previous cascade layer.

> If there is no other cascade layer to revert to for the matching CSS rule, the property value rolls back to the computed value derived from the current layer. Furthermore, if there is no matching CSS rule in the current layer, the property value for the element rolls back to the style defined in a previous style origin.

Different from the [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) keyword which reverts directly to the browser's defaults.

---

Additional ressources:

- Creating layers with [`@layer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer)
- [Style origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Style_origin). Used to determine where to stop rolling back the cascade of styles

---

The following should work (Again, if your browser is compatible)

Elements with class '*padding1*' will have a padding-top of 100px, unless they also have the class '*myDiv*' in which case the padding will be set back to 0, but if said element is inside a parent with class '*specialPage*', the padding will be reverted back to 100px.

```css
@layer base {
  .padding1 {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
}

@layer special {
  .myDiv {
      padding-top: 0;
   }
  .specialPage .myDiv {
    padding-top: revert-layer;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="specialPage">
  <div class="myDiv padding1">Inside specialPage original padding</div>
</div>

<div class="myDiv padding1">Outside specialPage no padding</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding-top: unset;` which would completely neutralize all previous properties of the same name for the same class. But in order to "rewind" the property that came before `padding-top: 0;` you need to declare it again.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You want style of *.padding1* to be implemented for both div. Am I right?
This can be done like this

```
<style>
   .padding1{
    padding-top: 100px !important;
}
 .myDiv {
    padding-top: 0; 
}
<style>
```

In HTML page

```
<div class="myDiv padding1"></div>
```

Now .myDiv will have **padding-top:100px;**

As .myDiv have own "padding-top:0" but it will show "padding-top:100px".

Hope it will solve you problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `initial` to set it to its default value.

```
    .myDiv {
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    .padding1 {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .specialPage .myDiv {
        padding-top: initial;
    }
```